# XSLT How to get an attribute value of the following-sibling node?

Tags: xml, xslt

Supose I have this XML:

```
<Items>
  <Car name="12">Mercedes</Car>
  <Bike name="23">Gt</Bike>
  <House name="gt">123</House>
  <Skate name="as">111</Skate>
  <Plane name="bb">5522</Plane>
  <tv name="sss">Sony</tv>
</Items>
```

And the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Items">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="*[position() mod 2 != 0]">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name(following-sibling::*)"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output Im getting is:

```
    <table>
  <tr>
    <td>Car</td>
    <td>Mercedes</td>
    <td>Bike</td>
    <td>Gt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>House</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Skate</td>
    <td>111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Plane</td>
    <td>5522</td>
    <td>tv</td>
    <td>Sony</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But what I need is the attribute `@name` instead of the node name... how can I do that??
What I need is this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Mercedes</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>Gt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>gt</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>as</td>
    <td>111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bb</td>
    <td>5522</td>
    <td>ss</td>
    <td>sony</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I know that in the first `<td>` I can use `@name`, but how can I get the attribute "name" of the following sibling node in the other `<td>`?

Answer (score 4):

```
<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*/@name"/>
```

This should return the name attribute of the following sibling.

Edit

---

It appears

```
 <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]/@name"/>
```

Is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Almost. `following-sibling::*/@name` returns the `@name` for **all** following siblings. You mean `following-sibling::*[1]/@name`.

Comment: @Tomalak, I thought the same, but Zirkonix's answer appears to work. Is there any reason why one *has* to index into the following siblings here?

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but if you don't specify any index, by default the `[1]` is taken. So the only reason to index would be to specify any other index than `[1]`.

Comment: It works without `[1]` because of the way nodesets are converted to strings (only the string value of the *first* node is taken). You should still add `[1]` because it's clearer and usually faster.

Comment: @Zirkonix You are indeed wrong. If there's no "index", all matching nodes are returned. It's only by accident that it doesn't make any difference here because of the way `<xsl:value-of>` behaves: as *nwellnhof* says, it converts its argument to string; in case of a node set this only affects the first node. `<xsl:apply-templates>` for example would consider all matched nodes.